# Python requests post won't return results

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to scrape marathon results data from marathonguides.com, but none of my POST requests appear to be working. I had code last week that worked just fine, but now, rather than returning the results of my request, it returns the original page to which I submitted the request. I am not getting any errors or anything, it's just as if I'm not submitting the search at all.

The site uses forms to search for race results. For example, to search for the Boston Marathon, you could go to their race search form (https://www.marathonguide.com/races/search.cfm) and type something like "Boston" for Marathon Name and hit the Search button.

Here's the code I had that worked a week ago:

```py
# Import modules
import requests

# Search for "Boston"
url = "http://www.marathonguide.com/races/search.cfm"
searchParams = {
    "MarName":"Boston",
    "state":0,
    "Country":0,
    "BeginDate":"",
    "EndDate":"",
    "submit":"Search"
}
res = requests.post(url,data=searchParams)
```

When I first inspected the contents of the requests, I got exactly what I expected - links to races with "Boston" in the name. Now, I just get the marathon search page back, with no results.

I've tried adding headers according to what I see the browser doing to the request as well, such as:

```py
url = "http://www.marathonguide.com/races/search.cfm"
searchParams = {
    "MarName":"Boston",
    "state":"0",
    "Country":"0",
    "BeginDate":"",
    "EndDate":"",
    "submit":"Search"
}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0",
    "Referer": "https://www.marathonguide.com/races/search.cfm"
}
res = requests.post(url,data=searchParams,headers=headers)
```

I still get the same search page back rather than the results, even with the headers.

Since the code worked last week but not now, maybe the folks who manage the site have made it harder to scrape their data? Or is their something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If the code worked last week, the cause is probably something that changed within the website you are trying to scrape from.

That may be many things depending on how their search function is made and it can be hard to know without any insight.

Maybe try and reach for them, to ask them directly ?

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I wanted to make sure the issue wasn't something on my end that I didn't understand first. I will go ahead and reach out, then.